# FileNotFoundException for URL that works in browser

Tags: java, ioexception

I am trying to use an API from https://us.mc-api.net/ for a project and I have made this as a test.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     try {
         URL url = new URL("http://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/193nonaxishsl/csv/");
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                }
          in.close();  
                 }
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("I/O Error");

                    }
                }
}
```

And this is giving me an IOException error but when ever I open the same page in my web browser I get

```
false,Unknown-Username
```

which is what I want to get from the code. I am new and don't really know why it is happening or why. 
EDIT: StackTrace

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/193nonaxishsl/csv/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at com.theman1928.Test.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: I actually thought this would have worked, Tracing it I can see line should have "false,Unknown-Username". Can you post the stack trace given when the IOException is thrown?

Comment: The given URL is returning a 404 Not Found HTTP error, despite it returning content to the browser. If this web service is yours, then get it to return a 200 OK instead and you'll be fine.

Comment: @ManoDestra It is not my service but if its thier problem I will try to contact them or find a different service I can use.

Comment: @JackAndrewMcKay Posted.

Comment: If you try with http://example.com/, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL is returning status code 404 and therefore the input stream (mild guess here) is not being created and therefore is null. Sort the status code and you should be OK.

Ran it with this CSV and it is fine: [other csv](http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv)

If the error code is important to you then you can use HttpURLConnection:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("code:"+conn.getResponseCode());
```

In that way you can process the response code before proceeding with a quick if-then-else check.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how the wire protocols are working in comparison with the java.net classes and an actual browser. A browser is going to be much more sophisticated than the simple java.net API you are using.

If you want to get the equivalent response value in Java, then you need to use a richer HTTP API.

This code will give you the same response as the browser; however, you need to download the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) jars

The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class TestDriver
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String url = "http://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/193nonaxishsl/csv";

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        getResponseFromHTTPReq(httpGet, url);
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getResponseFromHTTPReq(HttpUriRequest httpReq, String url)
{
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    // Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    try
    {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpReq);
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
    }

    if (entity == null)
    {
        String errMsg = "No response entity back from " + url;
        throw new RuntimeException(errMsg);
    }

    String returnRes = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader buf = null;
    try
    {
        is = entity.getContent();
        buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = null;
        while (true)
        {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            sb.append(s);
        }

        returnRes = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("Response: [" + returnRes + "]");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (buf != null)
        {
            try
            {
                buf.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
        if (is != null)
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    return returnRes;
}

}
```

**Outputs**:

> Response Code : 404
>
> Response: [false,Unknown-Username]

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with the Apache HTTP libraries. The API endpoint seems to return a status code of 404, hence your error. Code I used is below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("http://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/193nonaxishsl/csv/");
    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());   // 404
}
```

Switching out the `http://us.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/193nonaxishsl/csv/` with `www.example.com` or whatever returns a status code of 200, which further proves an error with the API endpoint. You can take a look at [[Apache HTTP Components] library here](https://hc.apache.org/).